# How Do I Use the route_translator gem and not require the Locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, routes, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm able to successfully use the route_translator gem when I require a locale. When I change between the two locales I have (en:fr) I have no problems clicking any of the links and displaying the correct views and link translations.

Here is my `config/routes.rb` file where my routes work as expected.

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do  

  scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do  
#  scope "(/:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

#    resources :pages

    localized do
#      resources :pages
      match "/about",      to: "pages#about", via: "get"
      match "/clients",    to: "pages#clients", via: "get"
      match "/contact",    to: "pages#contact", via: "get"
      match "/manage",     to: "pages#manage", via: "get"
      match "/media",      to: "pages#media", via: "get"
      match "/privacy",    to: "pages#privacy", via: "get"
      match "/system",     to: "pages#system", via: "get"
      match "/testpage",   to: "pages#testpage", via: "get"
    end

  end

  root                     to: "pages#home", via: :get
  match "/:locale" => "pages#home", via: :get, :as => "locale_root"

end
```

Here is the locale logic in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` which defaults the locale to **en** if no locale is found.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  private

    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = (params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?) || cookies[:locale] || I18n.default_locale || 'en'
      cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale 
    end

end
```

`rake routes`:

```
   about_fr GET  /:locale/qui_sommes_nous(.:format) pages#about {:locale=>"fr"}
   about_en GET  /:locale/about(.:format)           pages#about {:locale=>"en"}
 clients_fr GET  /:locale/clients(.:format)         pages#clients {:locale=>"fr"}
 clients_en GET  /:locale/clients(.:format)         pages#clients {:locale=>"en"}
 contact_fr GET  /:locale/contactez_nous(.:format)  pages#contact {:locale=>"fr"}
 contact_en GET  /:locale/contact(.:format)         pages#contact {:locale=>"en"}
  manage_fr GET  /:locale/gerer(.:format)           pages#manage {:locale=>"fr"}
  manage_en GET  /:locale/manage(.:format)          pages#manage {:locale=>"en"}
   media_fr GET  /:locale/edition(.:format)         pages#media {:locale=>"fr"}
   media_en GET  /:locale/media(.:format)           pages#media {:locale=>"en"}
 privacy_fr GET  /:locale/confidentialite(.:format) pages#privacy {:locale=>"fr"}
 privacy_en GET  /:locale/privacy(.:format)         pages#privacy {:locale=>"en"}
  system_fr GET  /:locale/systeme(.:format)         pages#system {:locale=>"fr"}
  system_en GET  /:locale/system(.:format)          pages#system {:locale=>"en"}
testpage_fr GET  /:locale/testpage(.:format)        pages#testpage {:locale=>"fr"}
testpage_en GET  /:locale/testpage(.:format)        pages#testpage {:locale=>"en"}
       root GET  /                                  pages#home
locale_root GET  /:locale(.:format)                 pages#home
```

The problem comes when I change the scope statement to the second one. I can display the locale_root path and switch locales with no problem. If I display another view in en I can switch the locale to fr and successfully display the view in French. However when I attempt to switch back to en the route drawn includes **/fr/en** instead of **/en**.

```
`rake routes` with `(/:locale)`:

   about_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/qui_sommes_nous(.:format) pages#about {:locale=>"fr"}
   about_en GET  (/:locale)/about(.:format)              pages#about {:locale=>"en"}
 clients_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/clients(.:format)         pages#clients {:locale=>"fr"}
 clients_en GET  (/:locale)/clients(.:format)            pages#clients {:locale=>"en"}
 contact_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/contactez_nous(.:format)  pages#contact {:locale=>"fr"}
 contact_en GET  (/:locale)/contact(.:format)            pages#contact {:locale=>"en"}
  manage_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/gerer(.:format)           pages#manage {:locale=>"fr"}
  manage_en GET  (/:locale)/manage(.:format)             pages#manage {:locale=>"en"}
   media_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/edition(.:format)         pages#media {:locale=>"fr"}
   media_en GET  (/:locale)/media(.:format)              pages#media {:locale=>"en"}
 privacy_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/confidentialite(.:format) pages#privacy {:locale=>"fr"}
 privacy_en GET  (/:locale)/privacy(.:format)            pages#privacy {:locale=>"en"}
  system_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/systeme(.:format)         pages#system {:locale=>"fr"}
  system_en GET  (/:locale)/system(.:format)             pages#system {:locale=>"en"}
testpage_fr GET  /fr(/:locale)/testpage(.:format)        pages#testpage {:locale=>"fr"}
testpage_en GET  (/:locale)/testpage(.:format)           pages#testpage {:locale=>"en"}
       root GET  /                                       pages#home
locale_root GET  /:locale(.:format)                      pages#home
```

The only routes that I have problems with are those within the localize do statement. They include all my available locales when I switch between **en** and **fr**.

I have looked at the configurations in GitHub. but I have not seen anything that looks like could solve my problem. The descriptions of the configurations don't say anything clearly that makes me think they will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem... the solution.

Change your file `..\config\routes.rb` to this:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do  

    localized do

      match "/about",      to: "pages#about", via: "get"
      match "/clients",    to: "pages#clients", via: "get"
      match "/contact",    to: "pages#contact", via: "get"
      match "/manage",     to: "pages#manage", via: "get"
      match "/media",      to: "pages#media", via: "get"
      match "/privacy",    to: "pages#privacy", via: "get"
      match "/system",     to: "pages#system", via: "get"
      match "/testpage",   to: "pages#testpage", via: "get"
      match "/",           to: "pages#home", via: "get", :as => :locale_root
    end
    root to: "pages#home", via: :get

end
```

You just need to remove the `scope` around the `localized`.

Also add the following to your `application.rb` file.

```
RouteTranslator.config do |config|
  config.force_locale = true
  config.locale_param_key = :locale
end
```

With this you will end with the following routes:

```
about_fr GET  /fr/qui_sommes_nous(.:format) pages#about {:locale=>"fr"}
about_en GET  /en/about(.:format)           pages#about {:locale=>"en"}
...
root_fr GET  /fr                                pages#home {:locale=>"fr"}
root_en GET  /en                                pages#home {:locale=>"en"}
root    GET  /                                  pages#home
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks! Now I want to see if I can use this and not require a locale defaulting to en.